# Cookie in AJAX response from other domain not honored - are there workarounds

Tags: ajax, api, cookies, cross-domain

I have a server-side API on the domain `api.example.com`

User is visiting `www.website.com` where a script makes an XmlHttpRequest to `api.example.com` and gets a response with a cookie.

It appears the API's response cookie is not honored by the HTTP agent.

I'm aware of the non-cross-domain-leaking-cookie policy, but I thought the domain here would be `api.example.com`. Seems I guessed wrong.

Is there some other way that my API on `api.example.com` could remember user data from one site to another? If not, how could services like Criteo and other retargeting sites work, from this point of view?

Comment: Do you set 1.: `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header to `true` in possible preflight response and regular response ?  2.: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header  to value of the origin from the actual request? 3.: Does the client set `XMLHttpRequest .withCredentials` to `true` ?

Comment: @MichalFoksa thanks, turns out it was the solution

Comment: would you mind if I turn the comment into answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your API set:

1. `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header to `true` in possible preflight response and regular response,
2. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header  to value of the origin from the actual request,
3. and client sets `XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials` to `true`.